# How to create a Visual Studio extension to display a block of color over a hex value?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsx

I was told that in Visual Studio I can "create an extension" to create a block of color when the cursor hovers over e.g. "DF7401" or "ffcccc".

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

As a popup or physically in the editor?

[This sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/IntraTextSample) shows how to replace them in the text, so you see the color instead of the hex value.

If you want to do it on hover, you could do it as an [IQuickInfoSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.iquickinfosource.aspx), which is the normal hover text help you get in VS.  I believe the [Ook! language sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ookLanguage) shows you how to add your own quick info source.